# How to generate a kerberos token without user input

Tags: java, kerberos, spnego, keytab

I'm trying to generate a Kerberos client token in java, in order to send it in a header for a kerberized service.

For that I created a jaas login conf, and a keytab for my user.
I want to generate the token automatically without any user input. For now I managed to create a token  but i'm being
prompted to enter the user's password, which is not what I want.
When I set the 'doNotPrompt' to 'true' (in the login.conf) I get an exception "unable to obtain password from user",
even though i'm specifying a keytab file.

I found very little code samples in the web, though eventually I used them. But I didn't find an answer to what i'm trying to do.
Does anyone know how to accomplish what I want?

My login.conf is:

```
com.sun.security.jgss.initiate {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required storeKey="true"
principal="HTTP/MyComp@DOMAIN" useKeyTab="true" 
keytab="c:\Users\me\Desktop\abc.keytab";
}
```

And my java code is:

```
String clientPrincipal = "HTTP/MyComp@DOMAIN";
String serverPrincipal = "HTTP/ServerComp@DOMAIN";
Oid oid = new Oid("1.2.840.113554.1.2.2");

try
{
    GSSManager manager = GSSManager.getInstance();
    GSSName gssUserName = manager.createName(clientPrincipal, GSSName.NT_USER_NAME, oid);
    GSSCredential clientGSSCreds = manager.createCredential(gssUserName.canonicalize(oid),
                        GSSCredential.INDEFINITE_LIFETIME,
                        oid,
                        GSSCredential.INITIATE_ONLY);

    GSSName gssServerName = manager.createName(serverPrincipal, GSSName.NT_USER_NAME);
    GSSContext clientContext = manager.createContext(
                        gssServerName.canonicalize(oid),
                        oid,
                        clientGSSCreds,
                        GSSCredential.INITATE_ONLY);

    clientContext.requestCredDeleg(true);
    byte[] token = clientContext.initSecContext(token, 0, token.length);

}
catch (GSSException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: `HTTP/MyComp@DOMAIN` is not a user principal, this is a service principal. Try with a service account if you intend to use a keytab.

Comment: What do you mean by service account?
The SPN is set to a dedicated account in Active Directory, which is used only for the purpose above.

Comment: Hi; If Glenn Lane answered your question please mark it as such which will verify it to others in the community; otherwise please let us know if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A keytab file can contain keys for different users, so you need to tell your login.conf the principal whose key you'll be using.  This principal name is arbitrary: it only needs to match the name you provided when you created the keytab (although I recommend using the actual UPN of the user).